# Show child taxonomies (that have posts) of the current parent taxonomy

Tags: categories

For the life of me I can't see why this isn't working. It works fine like this (normal categories)

```
<?php
if (is_category())
{
    $cur_cat = get_query_var('cat');
    if ($cur_cat) 
    {
        $new_cats = wp_list_categories('show_option_none=&echo=false&child_of=' . $cur_cat . '&depth=1&title_li=&show_count=1&hide_empty=1');
        echo '' . $new_cats . '';
    }
}
?>
```

But it doesn't work like this with a custom taxonomy...

```
<?php
if (is_taxonomy())
{
    $cur_catp = get_query_var('catp');
    if ($cur_catp) 
    {
        $new_catsp = wp_list_categories('show_option_none=&echo=false&child_of=' . $cur_catp . '&depth=1&title_li=&show_count=1&hide_empty=1&taxonomy=p_scales');
        echo '' . $new_catsp . '';
    }
}
?>
```

I need both to work side by side hence why I've changed the variables.

Comment: You should use `is_tax('p_scales')` and not `is_taxonomy()`..

Comment: That doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure the taxonomy `p_scales` is valid? And that the WordPress *query var* `catp` exists for the requested URL? Try `var_dump( $cur_catp )` and see if it's a proper ID of a valid term.

Comment: `p_scales` is definitely the custom taxonomy slug. I don't know what you mean by the query var `catp`?

Comment: Well, you got this code: `$cur_catp = get_query_var('catp');` in the question.. And did you try the `var_dump()` right after that code?

Comment: Where exactly do I put the `var_dump( $cur_catp )`?

Comment: After you defined `$cur_catp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Props to Sally for improving on this to show post count

```
$term = get_queried_object();

$children = get_terms( $term->taxonomy, array(
    'parent'    => $term->term_id,
    'hide_empty' => false
) );

if ( $children ) { 
    foreach( $children as $subcat )
    {
        echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url(get_term_link($subcat, $subcat->taxonomy)) . '">' . // wrapped
          $subcat->name . ' (' . $subcat->count . ')' . '</a></li>';
    }
}
```

### UPDATE

**To show the posts count:**

As pointed in the comment, and based on the above code, you can use `$subcat->count` to display the number of posts in the specific term.

Therefore I replaced the `$subcat->name . '</a></li>'` with:

```
$subcat->name . ' (' . $subcat->count . ')' . '</a></li>'
```

which outputs something like: `Term Name (1)`, `Another Term Name (0)`, etc.

**For the original code in question (using `wp_list_categories()`), here's how to fix it, and the fixed code:**

1. Replace the `is_category()` with `is_tax( 'p_scales' )`.
2. Replace the `get_query_var( 'cat' )` with `get_queried_object_id()`.

   ```
   if (is_tax('p_scales'))
   {
       $cur_cat = get_queried_object_id();
       if ($cur_cat)
       {
           $new_cats = wp_list_categories('show_option_none=&echo=false&child_of=' . // wrapped
             $cur_cat . '&depth=1&title_li=&show_count=1&hide_empty=1&taxonomy=p_scales');
           echo '' . $new_cats . '';
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: The only trouble i'm having with this is being able to show the number of posts next to each term? `show_count` doesn't work.

Comment: `show_count` is not a valid parameter for `get_terms()`, and you can retrieve the number of posts via the `count` column of the term data - `$subcat->count`.

Comment: If I ask nicely would you be able to show me :)

Comment: I've just edited your answer. I've also posted an answer to the original question regarding `wp_list_categories()` . I hope it helps you.

Comment: It works perfect. I just needed to change the `hide_empty` variable to true. Thanks heaps!

Comment: Thank you for allowing me to merge our answers. +1 :)